# How to force GMail show link in list

Tags: email, hyperlink, gmail

Several services, for example github, bitbucket and some ticket services able to send email which contain inlist link in GMail. Like that:
[image]

Inside they just put link.
[image]

How it is possible to do the same programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the right answer. The right name of this feature is Go-To Action. It’s possible to add it programmatically using microdata or JSON-LD. More details in [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/go-to-action)